# Sumif with only first value of each group in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset similar to this, but really extensive:

| Row | Levels | Level 1 | Size | Department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | AA | 2.0 | Dept 1 |
| 2 | 2 | AA | 0.8 | Dept 1 |
| 3 | 3 | AA | 1.5 | Dept 1 |
| 4 | 2 | BB | 3.0 | Dept 1 |
| 5 | 3 | BB | 2.0 | Dept 1 |
| 6 | 3 | BB | 2.5 | Dept 2 |
| 7 | 2 | CC | 5.0 | Dept 2 |
| 8 | 3 | CC | 1.5 | Dept 2 |
| 9 | 3 | DD | 0.5 | Dept 2 |
| 10 | 3 | DD | 3.0 | Dept 2 |
| 11 | 2 | EE | 4.0 | Dept 2 |
| 12 | 3 | EE | 2.0 | Dept 2 |

What I need is to achieve a total size per `Department`, however I want to sum **only the first match** per Level 1, i.e.:
Department 1 would be `2.0 (row 1) + 3.0 (row 4) = 5.0`
Department 2 would be `2.5 (row 6) + 5.0 (row 7) + 0.5 (row 9) + 4.0 (row 11) = 12.0`

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this in Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternate solution to the same formula:
`=SUM(XLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(C:C,(ROW(C:C)>1)*(E:E=@$F$2#))&@$F$2#),C:C&E:E,D:D))`

Where `F2` holds `=UNIQUE(FILTER(E:E,(ROW(E:E)>1)*(E:E<>"")))`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`SUMIFS()` will not do what you want.  Use `SUMPRODUCT()` with some boolean:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$13*($D$2:$D$13=F2)*(COUNTIFS(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,ROW($B$2:$B$13)-1),$B$2:$B$13,OFFSET($D$2,0,0,ROW($B$2:$B$13)-1),F2)=1))
```

One note, the use of `OFFSET()` makes this a volatile function, meaning that it will recalc with every change made to excel.  If there are too many then it will slow down the responsiveness in Excel.

[image]

---

To do it without the volatility we need a helper column.  In `E2` put:

```
=COUNTIFS($D$2:D2,D2,$B$2:B2,B2)=1
```

And copy down.  Then we can use `SUMIFS()`:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,D:D,F2,E:E,TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have Excel 365, you could try something like this:

```
=LET(FilteredLevel,FILTER(C$2:C$13,E$2:E$13=H2),
SUM(XLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FilteredLevel),FilteredLevel,FILTER(D$2:D$13,E$2:E$13=H2))))
```

[image]

*Note*

You can also use full-column references if you wish

```
=LET(FilteredLevel,FILTER(C:C,E:E=H2),
SUM(XLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FilteredLevel),FilteredLevel,FILTER(D:D,E:E=H2))))
```